# JavaScript dot notation does not work in process.env

Tags: node.js, dotenv

Why can't I access `process.env.TEST` with dot notation, what is the difference between dot notation and brackets notation here?

.env:

```
TEST=123
```

src/routes/index.svelte:

```
<script>
import '$lib/test';
</script>
```

src/lib/test.js:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

console.log(process.env.TEST, process.env['TEST']); // undefined 123
```

(I wrote the code in a new SvelteKit project, I did not change anything else except for the codes above)

Comment: can you try it with a string as the value in the dot env?

Comment: @AniketAgarwal I changed .env to `TEST="123"` and `TEST=string`, and the result is the same.

Comment: I am confused, try logging process.env and see if it is an object

Comment: It is an object that contains { TEST: 'string' } and other system environment variables.

Comment: umm then dot notation should work, make sure there are no typo errors and maybe restart your IDE lol

Comment: I just found out that in the output of `svelte-kit dev`, at /.svelte-kit/output/server/app.js, `process.env.TEST` is changed to `{}.TEST`, but `process.env["TEST"]` is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SvelteKit is using Vite for bundling, right? It seems that Vite does "production replacement" for env variables: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Here is how `import.meta.env` variables are replaced:

> During production, these env variables are statically replaced. It is therefore necessary to always reference them using the full static string. For example, dynamic key access like `import.meta.env[key]` will not work.

And plain access to `process.env` appears to be processed as well. For example, this source file:

```js
console.log('dot access', process.env.XDG_DATA_HOME);
console.log('indexing env', process['env'].XDG_DATA_HOME);
console.log('indexing var', process.env['XDG_DATA_HOME']);
```

...will be transformed by Vite to this:

```js
console.log("dot access", {}.XDG_DATA_HOME);
console.log("indexing env", process["env"].XDG_DATA_HOME);
console.log("indexing var", process.env["XDG_DATA_HOME"]);
```

As you can see, the first line was transformed. This makes sense if you want to use env variables to parametrize/customize a web script, but not if you run a bundled script in NodeJS.

As a workaround, use square brackets to access the `env` or the variable.

Here is a tracking issue in Vite: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3229